# Proof of existence of prime factorization (Educational)

Tags: proof, isabelle

I am trying to write a proof of the existence of the prime factorization of numbers. It is meant to be educational, so every function is defined, we try not to use Isabelle built in functions. Here is my code:

```
(* addition*)
primrec suma::"nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat" where
"suma 0 n = 0" |
"suma (Suc x) n = Suc (suma x n)"

primrec pred::"nat ⇒ nat" where
"pred 0 = 0" |
"pred (Suc x) = x"

(* substraction *)
primrec resta::"nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat" where
"resta m 0 = m" |
"resta m (Suc x) = pred (resta m x)"

primrec mult::"nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat" where
"mult 0 m = 0" |
"mult (Suc x) m = suma m (mult x m)"

lemma less_pred [simp]: "(x < y) ⟶ (pred x < y)"
proof (induct x)
case 0 then show ?case by simp
next
case (Suc x) then show ?case by simp
qed

lemma less_n_pred [simp]: "∀n::nat. (n ≠ 0) ⟶ (pred n < n)"
proof
fix n::nat show "n ≠ 0 ⟶ pred n < n" by (induct n) simp_all
qed

lemma less_resta [simp]: "(m > 0 ∧ n > 0) ⟶ (resta m n < m)"
proof (induct n)
case 0 then show ?case by simp_all
next
case (Suc x) then show ?case by force
qed

fun divi::"nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat" where
"divi m n = (if n = 0 then
                undefined
            else
              if m = 0 
                then 0 
              else Suc (divi (resta m n) n))"

fun modulo::"nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat" where
"modulo m n = (if n = 0 then
                undefined
            else
              if m < n 
                then m 
              else modulo (resta m n) n)"

definition divide::"nat ⇒ nat ⇒ bool" where
"divide m n = (modulo n m = 0)"

primrec numTo :: "nat ⇒ nat list" where
"numTo 0 = []" |
"numTo (Suc x) = (Suc x)#(numTo x)" 

primrec filter:: "'a list ⇒ ('a ⇒ bool) ⇒ 'a list" where
"filter [] p = []" |
"filter (x#xs) p = (if p x then x#(filter xs p) else filter xs p)"

definition divisores::"nat ⇒ nat list" where
"divisores n = (filter (numTo n) (λm. divide m n))"

definition is_prime::"nat ⇒ bool" where
"is_prime n = (length (divisores n) = 2)"

primrec all_prime::"nat list ⇒ bool" where
"all_prime [] = True" |
"all_prime (x#xs) = (is_prime x ∧ all_prime xs)"

primrec prod_list::"nat list ⇒ nat" where
"prod_list [] = 1" |
"prod_list (x#xs) = mult x (prod_list xs)"

lemma mult_num: "∀n::nat. n>1 ∧ ¬ is_prime n ⟶ (∃x y::nat. x < n ∧ y < n ∧ mult x y = n)"
proof
fix n::nat
(* This lemma might be useful? *)

theorem exists_prime_factor: "∀n::nat. (n > 1 ⟶ (∃xs::nat list. prod_list xs = n ∧ all_prime xs))"
proof
  fix n::nat
  show "(n > 1 ⟶ (∃xs::nat list. prod_list xs = n ∧ all_prime xs))"
  proof (induct n rule: less_induct)
 (* How can i prove this? *)
```

How can I prove theorem exists_prime_factor: `∀n::nat. (n > 1 ⟶ (∃xs::nat list. prod_list xs = n ∧ all_prime xs))`?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One short answer is that you started with a basic mistake in your definition of `suma`. It should be this (I guess):

```
primrec suma::"nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat" where
  "suma 0 n = n" |
  "suma (Suc x) n = Suc (suma x n)"
```

My long answer has to do with how to use `value`, `nitpick`, and `sledgehammer` to see if you're on the right track.

If you can't prove something, a quick thing to try is `sledgehammer`. If `sledgehammer` returns nothing at all, then it's a good idea to try `nitpick`.

If `nitpick` finds a counterexample, that's a good indicator that your conjecture is false, though no guarantee. *Underspecified* definitions due to `undefined`, `THE`, and `SOME` can cause that, or not defining all cases for `primrec`.

## Use `value` to do quick checks of your functions

Using `value` was the end result of me trying to figure things out, without completely sorting out all your logic.

```
value "mult 2 2" (* Suc (Suc 0) *)
```

From there, it was just finally seeing the obvious.

Use `value` to see if your functions are working right, though that requires that `value` inputs can be simplified by the code generator.

## Use `nitpick`, it's free

For things like this, I like to see if `sledgehammer` can work magic.

First, it's best to get rid of outer quantifiers, like this:

```
theorem exists_prime_factor: 
  "n > 1 --> (∃xs::nat list. prod_list xs = n ∧ all_prime xs)"
  apply(induct n, auto)
  sledgehammer
  oops
```

When `sledgehammer` returns nothing at all, then the conjecture is false, or you need to help it out.

Nitpick gave me the counterexample of `n = 2`, but it say it's *potentially spurious*, and you're using `undefined` in your definitions, which can mess up `nitpick`.

Eventually, I ran `nitpick` on your `lemma mult_num`, and it gave me a counterexample of `n = 4`.

One thing to try is to prove the negation of your theorem, which definitely proves that your theorem is false. I was trying to prove this:

```
theorem
  "(x >= 4) | (y >= 4) | ~(mult x y = 4)"
```

Finally, I said, "Hmmm, lets try something simple":

```
value "mult 2 2"
```

That was returning 2, which finally helped me see the obvious.

## Undefined may not be what you think it is

I was specifically looking for things that mess `nitpick` up, one of them being the use of `undefined`, such as your function here:

```
fun divi::"nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat" where
  "divi m n = (if n = 0 then undefined
               else if m = 0 then 0 
               else Suc (divi (resta m n) n))"
```

This is an example of where `value` is not going to help you out. It can't simplify this:

```
value "divi 3 0" (* divi (Suc (Suc (Suc 0))) 0  *)
```

If you follow past discussion of Isabelle/HOL terminology, some experts would prefer that `undefined` be called `underspecified`.

Here, this theorem cannot be proved:

```
theorem "divi n 0 ~= (1::nat)"
  apply(induct n, auto)
oops
```

Nitpick finds a counterexample:

```
theorem "divi n 0 ~= (1::nat)"
  nitpick (*
  Nitpick found a counterexample:

  Free variable:
    n = 1
*)
oops
```

But then, it's the same counterexample as for this:

```
theorem "divi n 0 = (1::nat)"
  nitpick
oops
```

Why all this? Because `undefined::nat` is a `nat`. If you never define it, such as with an axiom, then you can't say what `nat` is equal to, though it has to be equal to some unique `nat`.

How about 44?

```
theorem "(divi n 0 = 44) <-> undefined = (44::nat)"
  by(simp)
```

It seems there's an infinitely small chance that `n = 1023456`.

```
theorem "(divi n 0 = 1023456) <-> undefined = (1023456::nat)"
  by(simp)
```

The consequence? There are infinitely many jokes that could be made about this, of infinitesimal size humor.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer! It is very useful. However, I have some doubts about division. How would you define "divi" without using undefined? Returning a "Maybe nat"?

Comment: @Hector, that would be an idea to pursue, which would be using type `nat option`, but overall it wouldn't make everything extraordinarily easy. Instead of `undefined` you can just set it equal to 0. Then either figure out how to make `divi m 0 = 0` meaningful, or put conditions in your theorems to exclude that case. Your `divi` is off by 1. I think `m < n` might fix it. I tried to prove some simple things, but the difficulties led back to dealing with your prececessor function. As an educational exercise, you picked a difficult one.

Comment: Undefinedness in a total logic like HOL is tricky. Defining `x / 0 = undefined` is perfectly reasonable, as is leaving it unspecified. However, past experiences have shown that doing this does not really have any advantages; defining `x / 0 = 0`, on the other hand, is useful because many nice division laws still hold. Having division return a `nat option` seems the obvious solution, but then you have to constantly lift other arithmetic operations (like addition and multiplication) to `nat option`, which is very tedious.

Comment: @Manuel, my past experience, the disadvantage, has been that leaving anything undefined messes up the magic of the code generator (and nitpick). My current idea is to (nearly) always work in "option space". The tedius part is implementing all algebraic and order operators to operate on type option, with new ops which use a predicate to restrict the domain. The domain and range of all functions is then type option, except if there's good reason to not do that. Anything not mapped to `None` is the domain. Defining bijective functions becomes easy. I don't need new types to restrict the domain.